# UISplitViewController: программно прятать masterController (левую панель)

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, ios7

Есть UISplitViewController, на котором размещены leftbarMenuController и mainViewController. При старте приложения появляется пуш контроллер с описанием приложения и кнопкой "продолжить" (во время которого прячется UINavigationBar), а также еще некоторые окна. Повороты экрана (iPad) не обрабатываются, только landscape-режим. Нужно время от времени прятать leftbarMenuController, чтобы некоторые контроллеры с инфой были на весь экран. Как это можно сделать программно (если есть такая возможность)? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вам нужен сдвигающийся контроллер, то системных возможностей в UISplitViewController для такого не хватит. Используйте это:

[SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

По личным наблюдениям - лучшее решение среди подобных.

Comment: Нет, это совсем не то. Я его использовал как "шторку" в айфоне. На айпаде  немного по другому, там этот вариант не пройдет.

Comment: Вообщем пошел по Вашей рекомендации. Меньше волокиты.